# Asp.Net Foreach and groupby

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I want get all my records and group by `ProgramId` and then view this.

```
var userProgramsStats = (from a in db.Statistics where a.UserId == login.GetUserObject().UserId select a)
                .GroupBy(a => a.ProgramId);

ViewBag.userProgramsStats = userProgramsStats
```

And in template:

```
 @foreach (var item in ViewBag.UserProgramsStats)
 {
     @item.MoneyRate
 }
```

Unfortunately I see this error:

> An unhandled exception has occurred: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'MoneyRate'

I must get all records where userid, and then groupby `programid` and sum one column `MoneyRate`. Then I want use like this:

```
@item.MoneyRate<br /> // sum MoneyRate
@item.OthercolumnNormal
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is due to the wrong type of object of your data `item`:
While processing the foreach, the type of your data is not recognized.

You should specify a Data Model :

```
public class UserStat {

   public double MoneyRate { get; set; }
   public string ColumnNormal {get; set;} 

   public UserStat() { }
   public UserStat(double moneyRate, string columnNormal)
   {
       MoneyRate = moneyRate;
       ColumnNormal = columnNormal;
   }
}
```

Then in your template, you should :

```
@foreach (UserStat item in ViewBag.UserProgramsStats)
{
    @item.MoneyRate
}
```

You might also do something like this:

```
@foreach (dynamic item in ViewBag.UserProgramsStats)
{
    @item.MoneyRate
}
```

Using the `dynamic` keyword will evaluate if the property exist at run time.

Comment: Thanks , but when i do "dynamic" I dont see any error but records too..

My query:

var userProgramsStats = (from a in db.Statistics where a.UserId == login.GetUserObject().UserId select a)
                .GroupBy(a => a.ProgramId).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a type error because the type of userProgramsStats does not contain a property MoneyRate.

You say you want to sum the MoneyRate column, to do this you need to project the grouped result into a new type.

Taking your existing query I've added a select statement onto the end of it that projects into a new anonymous type the programId and the sum of the MoneyRate column for each programId.

```
var result = (from a in db.Statistics where a.UserId login.GetUserObject().UserId select a)
                .GroupBy(a => a.programid)
                .Select(group => new { MoneyRateSum = group.Sum(i => i.MoneyRate), ProgramId = group.Key });
```

For more information on projecting and anonymous types read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397914.aspx.

Comment: The same error.. An unhandled exception has occurred: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'MoneyRateSum'

Comment: How about if you include the projection above, with the dynamic type in the view template suggested above?

`@foreach (dynamic item in ViewBag.UserProgramsStats)
{
    @item.MoneyRateSum
}`